# How to upload photos taken from iPhone to iCloud Photo Library?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, camera

I want to upload photos I take in iPhone to iCloud Photo Library automatically. I set `iCloud Photo Library` to on in iPhone's `Photos & Camera` Settings.

However, although all photos I capture using a simultaneous hold on *Home button* and *Power button* are uploaded automatically to the iCloud Photo Library, photos I take manually using *Camera* app are NOT uploaded.

Also, the videos I take using the same *Camera* app are uploaded automatically.

Why are photos not uploaded properly? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Set "Upload to My Photo Stream" on in Photos and Camera Settings